# How to type mongoose model when converted toObject

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose

I am creating mongoose model like this using typescript

```
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from "mongoose";
 
interface ItemModel extends Document {
  fullName: string;
  identifier: string;
}

const ItemSchema: Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  fullName: {
    type: String,
  },
  identifier: {
    type: String,
  }
});

export const Item = mongoose.model<ItemModel>("item",ItemSchema);
```

Than i create function that should search if some item already exist in mongodb like this

```
function alreadyExistInDb(identifier: string) {
  return new Promise<{} | false>((resolve, reject) => {
    Item.findOne({ identifier: identifier }, function (err, result) {
      if (result) { //result here is of type ItemModel
        resolve(result.toObject());
      } else {
        resolve(false);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Here i am not sure how to type result.toObject inside Promise.

Comment: "Here i am not sure how to type result.toObject inside Promise" do you mean you are not sure which type should be returned from the function?

Comment: @Kapobajza yes I am not sure how to type this part what promise resolves to. Promise<this>

Comment: Since you're returning an object from the response, the type could be `{ [key: string]: any; }`.

Comment: @Kapobajza yes but i want to get exact fields of that object. is that possible ? to inherit them somehow from ItemModel

Comment: Why don't you just return the `ItemModel` type? `return new Promise<ItemModel>`. Or do you want to make it more generic?

Comment: @Kapobajza That is a good question. This is my old code so i am not sure why i was converting it to object. Thanks